# How to call method of a generic input type class

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have a class

```
    public abstract class CommonService<T,U> : IService<T> where T : NameDTO where U : IRepository
    {
      public async Task SaveData(T editObj, int Id, short TypeId)
            {
              .. implementation
            }
    }
```

I have to call the method inside this class, so I am trying below method:

```
CommonService<XYZFiltersDTO, IXYZRepository> _commonService;
            await _commonService.SaveData(myObj, 23, 12);
```

but I am getting error at

> await _commonService.SaveData(myObj, 23, 12);

"use of unassigned local variable _commonService."

Comment: Well you need to assign something to `_commonService`.

Comment: What part of the error makes you think it's anything to do with the *call* to the method? You're using `_commonService`. It's *not been initialized*.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with generics - you'd get the same thing if you wrote `string text; int length = text.Length;`

Comment: @himBromBeere Yes, but I am not sure how to initiate a generic class instance? I tried CommonService<XYZFiltersDTO, IXYZRepository> _commonService = new CommonService<XYZFiltersDTO, IXYZRepository>(); but that didn't work either

Comment: "didn't work either" isn't an error message. What error message did you get when you tried that?

Comment: @damien_The_Unbeliever CommonService<XYZFiltersDTO, IXYZRepository> is a type, which is not valid in the given context. **This is the error I am getting**

Comment: Well you can't create an instance of an `abstract` class. It really looks like this is code you are trying to understand as a new C# developer, perhaps you would be better off running through some C# tutorials?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinity you should create a non abstract instance of your service, its implementation

Comment: You should definitly read about what an abstract type is and why you can´t instantiate it. We Can´t help you on this, as it´s simply too broad for a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have said, you can't create an instance of abstract class. You must create a class that implements it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/implement-abstract-class?view=vs-2017